# Simulate a USB flash drive with PC

Tags: driver, usb-flash-drive

I have a peculiar question.
The case is that I have a TV that can use as source a USB flash drive for playing movies.
Do you think it would be possible to directly connect a PC and the TV USB to USB and using some software interface to determine the PC to act like a flash drive.
I think it can be done with a hardware driver, but I'm wondering if it can be done without that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, you can't, not even by writing a new driver.

A flash drive is a USB device, but your computer has only USB host ports.  There's different circuitry needed in a device vs. a host (there are circuits that can do both, called USB on-the-go, but those are only found in peripherals).

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you can - kind of.

http://www.eye.fi

This is a special adapter with a Wi-Fi adapter built in that allows you to connect to a computer (or the Internet).

Not quite what you asked but the effect is similar.